# Jupyter notebook permission denied

Tags: 18.04, permissions, jupyter

I'm using Ubuntu 18.04 and whenever I run the command ***`jupyter notebook`*** in the terminal, it shows

***`Access to the file was denied
The file at /run/user/1000/jupyter/nbserver-10831-open.html is not readable.
It may have been removed, moved, or file permissions may be preventing access.`***

on the browser. I've tried uninstalling and reinstalling anaconda again and again.

Comment: Clarification: "[...] tried uninstalling and reinstalling anaconda again and again." Since Ubuntu 18.04, Jupyter Notebook is [available in the repository](https://packages.ubuntu.com/search?keywords=jupyter&searchon=names&suite=all&section=all) and that is the easiest way; why not just install Jupyter Notebook via APT?

Comment: @clearkimura doesn't help. I'm still receiving the same message. I don't think installation is the problem here.

Comment: Suggestion: Edit your question and include: output of `ls -l /run/user/1000` (check the subfolder permission, and whether exist or not). That may help others to answer this question.